# Can you please explain this joke by Samuel Johnson?

Tags: jokes

In *Life of Johnson*, we read the following:

> a fellow having attacked him with some coarse raillery, Johnson answered him thus, 'Sir, your wife, *under pretence of keeping a bawdy-house*, is a receiver of stolen goods.'

I can't seem to figure what this means.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that link.  That helps, although I'm not sure any of those answers are definitive.